# Close / Dispose of WordprocessingDocument from Open Xml Sdk aways changes Date modified of the file

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

Using [WordprocessingDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument?view=openxml-2.8.1) to modify .**docx** files, but the **Date modified** of the file is always changed after disposing the file even if no changes are made.

I've tried to disable `AutoSave` - date is still modified.

This piece of code leads to change of the date

```
using(var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true, new OpenSettings { AutoSave = false }))
{
}
```

Is there any way to avoid changes to the Date modified of the file when no changes are actually made?

---

**Env**: NET Core 3.0, [Open xml sdk](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK), [Nuget version 2.9.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/2.9.1)

Comment: Why are you opening the file in editable mode if you don't want to change it? See the second argument, set it to false.

Comment: @KubaOber I need to compare single paragraph from the document with external resource and replace it in the document if there is change.

Comment: @KubaOber Yes, disabling the editing mode did not change 'date modified' of the file. Opening the file twice will be the easiest way to go. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first open in non-editable mode, do the comparison, and then reopen in editable mode should there be a need to change the file.